# df reports missing space?

Tags: disk, df

This is part of `df -h`

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1        222G  5.5G  205G   3% /
```

222 - 5.5 = 205?

I also observe this in another physical machine

```
/dev/sda1       108G  3.9G   99G   4% /
/dev/sdb1       688G   29G  625G   5% /storage
```

688 - 29 = 625

Ubuntu sucks at math lol

Jokes aside, why is this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's the space set aside for the file address table.  It's reserved (so not actually available) but unused (since it doesn't have addresses yet) but it is part of total drive space (even if only system can use it).